# Is there a versatile and small flash bracket for macro?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, flash, macro, off-camera-flash, flash-bracket

I need a flash bracket for macro work with my Canon 430EX. But I'm looking for something versatile and smaller than the big ones I find online. Is there any type of bracket I can buy, possibly with a cable that can be connected to the DSLR directly?

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you mean by "versatile" in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do macro work with you 430 flash, you can search for some in [BH Photo](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/Brackets/ci/653/N/4168864826). You can find many types of bracket, from small L shape, to multiple holding plate there. But if you want a versatile and small flash for macro work, I suggest the Macro Ring, like Macro Ring Lite MR-14EX of Canon.